# Plot dates in Pandas with line connecting their duration

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains two columns with dates astype Timestamps. I would like to plot a figure where the time between those dates is 1 and the time outside those dates is 0: kinda like an 'active on/off' binary situation. I have discretised and indexed the whole day in intervals of 1 minute. After that, I am checking if the index is between time1 and time2, if it is then I am putting 1 to a new column else 0. This works but I think it's an overkill

```
                time1                 time2
0 2021-06-06 16:55:07.871   2021-06-06 21:03:06.931
1 2021-06-06 19:59:37.209   2021-06-06 21:09:20.265
2 2021-06-06 18:29:59.168   2021-06-06 19:00:53.479
3 2021-06-06 17:51:50.542   2021-06-06 19:06:56.697
4 2021-06-06 16:40:42.858   2021-06-06 17:58:44.572
```

Comment: I do not get your comment. 1/0 is standard lingo for binary activations

Comment: Apparently asking questions to help someone is considered rude. Sorry I didnt understand you, good luck.

Comment: Thank you. It's you ironic way which I believe is inherent in your character. Thanks again

Comment: Do you have a different dataset having timestamps which you are comparing whether it lies in between above 2 timestamps or not?

Comment: I have discretised and indexed the whole day in intervals of 1 minute. After that, I am checking if the index is between time1 and time2, if it is then I am putting 1 to a new column else 0. This works but I think it's an overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [plotly timeline](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.timeline.html) to simply plot when a sensor is on or off.  I added a row to your sample as sensor is always on across the 5 rows.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                time1                 time2
0  2021-06-06 16:55:07.871   2021-06-06 21:03:06.931
1  2021-06-06 19:59:37.209   2021-06-06 21:09:20.265
2  2021-06-06 18:29:59.168   2021-06-06 19:00:53.479
3  2021-06-06 17:51:50.542   2021-06-06 19:06:56.697
4  2021-06-06 16:40:42.858   2021-06-06 17:58:44.572
5  2021-06-06 22:40:42.858   2021-06-06 22:58:44.572"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df["time1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time1"])
df["time2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time2"])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="time1", x_end="time2", y=np.repeat(0, len(df)))
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"visible":False})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first make one column for time:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='senor', value_vars=['time1','time2'], value_name='time')
```

I prefer plotly express, its easy to use

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line(df, x='time', y='sensor', color'sensor')
```

it will draw a line when the sensor is on, and nothing when it's off.

this might be a good start for you :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using matplotlib's [`plt.hlines()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) function. You may have to customize the tick labels.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hlines(df.index, df.time1, df.time2)
```

[image]